# Restructure Unicode text file to N columns (vim/unix)

Tags: unix, vim

I am aware that you can restructure text in vim to a certain textwidth via `set textwidth=N`, `gg`, then `gqG`. This works fine with ascii files but I have files composed entirely in Unicode (Chinese characters) and it doesn't work as intended.

Is it not possible to restructure Unicode characters to adhere to a textwidth in vim? If not, is there some way using unix tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put into your vimrc

```
set formatoptions+=m
```

The line wrapping should work now.

More on this

```
:h mbyte-options
:h fo-table
```

Comment: It doesn't respect some of the original line breaks, but it does the job - thanks.

Comment: You can try use `set formatoptions+=mM`. Is it better?

Comment: I am sorry about that. It seems that it is not really easy (talk [here](http://vim_use.narkive.com/fDYaWweH/characters-that-should-not-appear-at-the-beginning-or-end-of-a-line)).

Comment: Also [this](http://yang3wei.github.io/blog/2013/01/28/she-zhi-vim-mo-ren-bian-ma-wei-utf-8/) and [this](http://www.cnblogs.com/luosongchao/p/3887376.html) could be helpful.